# How do I get my accidentally disabled side menu back?

Tags: 7, blocks, routes

I accidentally deactivated the left side menu for every page. I think it's still there, just deactivated.

How do I get it back?

Comment: Go to the block administration page. It sounds like you disabled the navigation menu block.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: `admin/structure/block`

Then move to the bottom of the page and search `Navigation` and in the select you must select `Sidebar First`, then go to the bottom and click the <kbd>Save blocks</kbd> button

See this picture:

[image]

Comment: @Roseanne a pleasure, don't forget check the answer as correct, if you don know how, see this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour